# Could not find the correct Provider<Products> above this ProductItemScreen Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this ProductItemScreen Widget whenever I press on a product Item even though I have set my provider as a parent of MaterialApp()

Below is the **product_overview_screen.dart** file which shows a gridview of the products on my screen

```
class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/prod_overview_Screen';
  const ProductsOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final prodData = Provider.of<Products>(context); //Recieves data from provider file
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Shop'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        ),
        itemCount: prodData.items.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
          imageUrl: prodData.items[i].imageUrl,
          title: prodData.items[i].title,
          id: prodData.items[i].id,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is also the **Product_item.dart** file where I pass the Id of the product to the next screen where I display the data of that particular product on the screen

```
class ProductItemScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/prod_item_screen';
  const ProductItemScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final prodIdPassed = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    final prod = Provider.of<Products>(context).findById(prodIdPassed);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(prod.title),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [Image.asset(prod.imageUrl), Text(prod.title)],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also below is the **main.dart** file where I have setup my provider for all available listeners

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Products(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.purple),
        initialRoute: ProductsOverviewScreen.routeName,
        routes: {
          ProductsOverviewScreen.routeName: (ctx) =>
              const ProductsOverviewScreen(),
          ProductItemScreen.routeName: (ctx) => const ProductItemScreen(),
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Does your **Products** provider service extend ChangeNotifier? Please make sure.

Comment: Yes please it does

Answer (score 0):

Right below runApp, explicitly declare the class:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<Products>(
```

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt provided providermodel  class here Check this provider.

[image]

**Mainmethod** (not changed)

```
  void main() {
      var changeNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (ctx) => Products(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.purple),
          initialRoute: ProductsOverviewScreen.routeName,
          routes: {
            ProductsOverviewScreen.routeName: (ctx) =>
                const ProductsOverviewScreen(),
            ProductItemScreen.routeName: (ctx) => const ProductItemScreen(),
          },
        ),
      );
    
      runApp(changeNotifierProvider);
    }
```

**Products provider** (Added)

```
 class Products extends ChangeNotifier {
  Product? _findById;
  List<Product> _items = [];

  List<Product> get items => _items;

  set items(List<Product> value) {
    _items = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set items2(List<Product> value) {
    _items = value;
    // notifyListeners();
  }

  Product? get findById => _findById;

  set findById(Product? value) {
    _findById = _items.where((element) => element.id == value!.id).first;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set findById2(Product? value) {
    _findById = _items.where((element) => element.id == value!.id).first;
    // notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Sample Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  var changeNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (ctx) => Products(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.purple),
      initialRoute: ProductsOverviewScreen.routeName,
      routes: {
        ProductsOverviewScreen.routeName: (ctx) =>
            const ProductsOverviewScreen(),
        ProductItemScreen.routeName: (ctx) => const ProductItemScreen(),
      },
    ),
  );

  runApp(changeNotifierProvider);
}

class ProductItemScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/prod_item_screen';

  const ProductItemScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final prodIdPassed = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    var product = new Product(imageUrl: "", title: "", id: prodIdPassed);
    Provider.of<Products>(context).findById2 = product;
    final prod = Provider.of<Products>(context).findById;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(prod!.title),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [Image.network(prod.imageUrl), Text(prod.title)],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/prod_overview_Screen';

  const ProductsOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final prodData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    List<Product> item = [];
    item.add(Product(
        imageUrl:
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/14/08/apparel-162192_1280.png",
        title: "lava",
        id: "1"));
    item.add(Product(
        imageUrl:
            "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/classic-accessories-1516305397.jpg",
        title: "hi",
        id: "2"));
    item.add(Product(
        imageUrl: "https://images.indianexpress.com/2019/09/toys.jpg",
        title: "hi",
        id: "4"));
    item.add(Product(
        imageUrl: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51zEsraniRL._UX569_.jpg",
        title: "hi",
        id: "3"));
    prodData.items2 = item; //Recieves data from provider file
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Shop'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        ),
        itemCount: prodData.items.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
          imageUrl: prodData.items[i].imageUrl,
          title: prodData.items[i].title,
          id: prodData.items[i].id,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  var imageUrl;

  var id;

  var title;

  ProductItem({Key? key, this.imageUrl, this.title, this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var column = Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            // height: 125,
            child: Image.network(
              imageUrl,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
            child: Text(
          title + "   " + id,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ))
      ],
    );

    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductItemScreen.routeName,
              arguments: id);
        },
        child: column);
  }
}

class Product {
  var title;

  var imageUrl;

  var id;

  Product({this.imageUrl, this.title, this.id});
}

class Products extends ChangeNotifier {
  Product? _findById;
  List<Product> _items = [];

  List<Product> get items => _items;

  set items(List<Product> value) {
    _items = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set items2(List<Product> value) {
    _items = value;
    // notifyListeners();
  }

  Product? get findById => _findById;

  set findById(Product? value) {
    _findById = _items.where((element) => element.id == value!.id).first;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set findById2(Product? value) {
    _findById = _items.where((element) => element.id == value!.id).first;
    // notifyListeners();
  }
}
```